# How to pass multiple errors as props from a single component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React component, I want to pass multiple errors as props to another component, like if array data is null, will show 'Data Not Found' or if any backend issue occurs then that specific error like 'Error 404'

Consider following code snippet:

```
import ErrorCard from "./ErrorCard";

const newData = [
  {
    id: "234abc",
    name: "John",
    age: 26
  },
  {
    id: "234pqr",
    name: "Adams",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    id: "123edf",
    name: "Rock",
    age: 29
  }
];

const DataStream = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {newData == "" ? (
        <ErrorCard data={newData} />
      ) : (
        newData.map((data) => <h5>{data.name}</h5>)
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default DataStream;
```

Now in another component where I want to pass all errors as props

```
const ErrorCard = ({ data }) => {
  return <>{data == "" ? <h4>No records</h4> : <h4>Error occured</h4>}</>;
};
```

What my intention is to make 'ErrorCard' as generic component and would be used in any other components. Whether the data is null or data has backend error all should be passed to that 'ErrorCard' component.

What could be the best solution?

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-driscoll-wov4q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of if-else with ternary operator, I will create a `mapError` function to return an error message from the error code like below.

```js
const mapError = (code) => {
  const defaultErrorMessages = {
    "404": "Not found",
    "500": "Server error. Please try again",
    ...
  };
  return defaultErrorMessages[code];
};
```

The API response should have 2 versions success data and error data.

```js
const successData = [
  {
    id: "234abc",
    name: "John",
    age: 26
  },
  {
    id: "234pqr",
    name: "Adams",
    age: 32
  },
  {
    id: "123edf",
    name: "Rock",
    age: 29
  }
];

const errorData = {
  error: "error",
  code: "404",
  message: "Error message to display"
};
```

Demo [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-tree-jolxi?file=/src/components/ErrorCard.js).